# using "set" twice for combining data sets in SAS

Tags: sas, set

This is a SAS code and I am learning about data combination.
I don't understand what data in what data set gets into the new combine data set.

I tried to google about this syntax, but I couldn't find nice explanation.

I'll greatly appreciate it if you explain about this, or provide some keywords I can search again.

```
data one;
input a b;
cards;
1 5
2 6
;
data three;
input a b e;
cards;
21 24 29
22 25 30
23 26 31
;

data combine;
set one;
set three;
by a;
run;
```

Comment: This is covered in the documentation with a decent amount of details IMO and the examples help a lot. https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=n1tgk0uanvisvon1r26lc036k0w7.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n00etw6t13f9dan1rpoxaqxgbicp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what your data step is doing.

On the first iteration it will:

1. Read the first observation from ONE, which will set A=1 and B=5.
2. Read the first observation from THREE, which will set A=21, B=24 and E=29.
3. At the end it will output. So A=21,B=24 and E=29.

Note that the BY statement will not have any effect (unless THREE is not sorted by A).

Then on the second iteration the same will happen with the second observations from each dataset.

On the third iteration the data step will stop when it reads past the end of the dataset ONE.

Did you intend to instead interleave the records from the two datasets? In that case you would want just a single SET statement that includes both datasets.

```
 set one three;
 by a;
```

Then the BY statement makes sense. It will insure that the records are read and written in order of the value of A.  Note that for your example data it doesn't matter if the BY statement is included or not because all values of A in ONE are smaller than the smallest value of A in THREE.

Answer (score 0):

The BY Statement in your last data step has no function in your example, you'd get the same result if you leave it out. For more information on BY group processing you could read https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/forum2007/222-2007.pdf.

Regarding the SET Statements you will find the answer in https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi23/Begtutor/p50.pdf together with lots of other usefull information regarding this topic.